# S + Z + 0 makes edge go to the 3D cursor

Tags: mesh

I'm trying to straight an edge but it's going to the 3D cursor. I obviously activated something accidentally but I don't know what or how.

Comment: You set the pivot point to the cursor: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/pivot_point/index.html .  You probably want the pivot point to be the median instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm quite sure you set the pivot point to *3D Cursor*. You should probably change it to *Median Point* or *Bounding Box Center*. If you're trying to flatten several elements at once, you can use *Individual Origins*, which works like *Median Point* but for each element individually (if you select two faces that are connected, they will be treated as a single element), or you can use *Active Element*, which puts the pivot point at the median of the active element, which is normally the last selected element.

[image]